# Plane curves isomorphic to the affine line

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $C$ be a plane curve parametrized by $x=f(t),y=g(t)$ where $f(t),g(t)\in k[t]$. We can easily see that the coordinate ring of $C$ is isomorphic to $k[f(t),g(t)]\subset k[t]$. So $C$ is isomorphic to the affine line $\mathbb{A}^1$ if $k[f(t),g(t)]=k[t]$. For example, the curve given by $x=t+t^4,y=t^2$ is isomorphic to the affine line.

My question is that whether all curves that are given by $x=f(t),y=g(t)$ with $k[f(t),g(t)]=k[t]$ are of such kind, i.e., satisfy a relation of the form $x-ay^n=bt+c$ or $y-ax^n=bt+c$ for some $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and constants $a,b,c$?

In algebraic terms, I am asking the following question:

> If $k[f(t),g(t)]=k[t]$, does it necessary that the relation of $f(t),g(t)$ and $t$ is of the form $f-ag^n=bt+c$ or $g-af^n=bt+c$?

Note: The [Abhyankar–Moh theorem](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Abhyankar%E2%80%93Moh_theorem) states that if $k[f(t),g(t)]=k[t]$, then $\deg f$ divides $\deg g$ or $\deg g$ divides $\deg f$. We may take $k=\mathbb{C}$ if necessary.

Comment: I don't think you need $k[f(t), g(t)] = k[t]$ to get $C$ isomorphic to the affine line (unless you specifically want the parametrization map to be an isomorphism). $k[f(t), g(t)] \cong k[t]$ is good enough. This happens for instance if $f(t) = t^{2}$ and $g(t) = t^{4}.$

Comment: Also, you might want to change your conditions to $f - ag^{n} = bt + c$. It's easy to get constants. Take $f = t^{2}, g = t + 1$ for example.

Comment: @Venkatesh:Thank you fou your useful comments!I have edited my question as you suggested.Do you have a answer to this question?

Comment: Google Lüroth’s Theorem.

Comment: @Lubin:I can't see how Lüroth’s Theorem is related to this question.Lüroth’s Theorem:All intermediate fields between $K$ and $K(t)$ are of the form $K(f(t))$ for some rational function $f(t)\in K(t)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can take for example $f=t+t^2$, $g=t^2+f^2$.